# Ajax call reloads page in FrontAccounting, a PHP ERP solution

Tags: php, ajax

I am using FrontAccounting a PHP Based open source ERP solution.

While adding items on Sales or Inventory pages, the Ajax Call leads to page reload.

How to prevent this issue.

The data gets lost and the user is highly frustrated.

Comment: I have tested using their [official demo page](https://demo.frontaccounting.eu/)- inserting a new item on inventory page will not reload the page